# Retrofit2 and DBFlow to Read Save and Entity Details

Tags: android, retrofit2, dbflow

I am using retrofit2 to make network requests for some resource. The corresponding response expected is this:

```
{
            "coach_details":[
            {
                "coach_id": 8,
                "academy_id": 1,
                "username": "coach2@gmail.com",
                "first_name": "David",
                "last_name": "test",
                "gender": "male",
                "email": "",
                "mobile": "", 
                "middle_name": "",
                "nick_name": "", 
                "state": "3"
            }
            ],
            "status": 1,
            "message": "success"
        }

        or

        {
            "status": 0,
            "message": "Oops! Invalid username or password!"
        }
```

This is a login endpoint for my application and subsequently I have added DBFLow as the ORM database. I am using the same model class for both DBFlow and retrofit2 like below:

Coach class which is main response:

```
public class Coach {

private String status;
private String message;

@SerializedName("coach_details")
private CoachDetails coachDetails;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public CoachDetails getCoachDetails() {
    return coachDetails;
}

public void setCoachDetails(CoachDetails coachDetails) {
    this.coachDetails = coachDetails;
}
}
```

and Coach Details which is object to save

```
@Table(database = SportsDatabase.class)
public class CoachDetails extends BaseModel {

@SerializedName("coach_id")
@PrimaryKey
@Column
public String coachId;

@SerializedName("academy_id")
public String academyId;

@SerializedName("username")
public String username;

@SerializedName("first_name")
public String firstName;

@SerializedName("last_name")
public String lastName;

@SerializedName("gender")
public String gender;

@SerializedName("mobile")
public String mobileNum;

@SerializedName("email")
public String emailAddr;

@SerializedName("middle_name")
public String midName;

@SerializedName("nick_name")
public String nickName;

@SerializedName("state")
public String originState;

public CoachDetails() {
}

public String getCoachId() {
    return coachId;
}

public void setCoachId(String coachId) {
    this.coachId = coachId;
}

public String getAcademyId() {
    return academyId;
}

public void setAcademyId(String academyId) {
    this.academyId = academyId;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getMobileNum() {
    return mobileNum;
}

public void setMobileNum(String mobileNum) {
    this.mobileNum = mobileNum;
}

public String getEmailAddr() {
    return emailAddr;
}

public void setEmailAddr(String emailAddr) {
    this.emailAddr = emailAddr;
}

public String getMidName() {
    return midName;
}

public void setMidName(String midName) {
    this.midName = midName;
}

public String getNickName() {
    return nickName;
}

public void setNickName(String nickName) {
    this.nickName = nickName;
}

public String getOriginState() {
    return originState;
}

public void setOriginState(String originState) {
    this.originState = originState;
}

public void insertInfo(String coach_id, String acadId, String username, String first, String last, String gender, String mobile, String mid_name, String nick, String state) {
    this.coachId = coach_id;
    this.academyId = acadId;
    this.username = username;
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.mobileNum = mobile;
    this.midName = mid_name;
    this.nickName = nick;
    this.originState = state;
}
}
```

and in my activity I have tried saving after network call like below code and also tried to test read from the database but getting null values in log. Is my save done properly or my read query is wrong?
Sample code:

```
private void attemptLogin(String username, String pwd) {
    Call<Coach> call = RestClient.getRestInstance()
            .getLoginService()
            .loginCoach("testcoach@gmail.com", "123@abcd"); // TODO: 12/17/2018 Use input values

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Coach>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Coach> call, Response<Coach> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                Coach coach = response.body();

                coach_id = coach.getCoachDetails().getCoachId();

                String acadId = coach.getCoachDetails().getAcademyId();
                String username = coach.getCoachDetails().getUsername();
                String first = coach.getCoachDetails().getFirstName();
                String last = coach.getCoachDetails().getLastName();
                String gender = coach.getCoachDetails().getGender();
                String mobile = coach.getCoachDetails().getMobileNum();
                String email = coach.getCoachDetails().getEmailAddr();
                String mid_name = coach.getCoachDetails().getMidName();
                String nick = coach.getCoachDetails().getNickName();
                String state = coach.getCoachDetails().getOriginState();
 //                    Log.d(TAG, "State:\t" + state);

                CoachDetails coachDetails = new CoachDetails();
//                    coachDetails.insertInfo(coach_id, acadId, username, first, last, gender, mobile, mid_name, nick, state);
                coachDetails.setCoachId(coach_id);
                coachDetails.setAcademyId(acadId);
                coachDetails.setFirstName(first);
                coachDetails.setLastName(last);
                coachDetails.setGender(gender);
                coachDetails.setMobileNum(mobile);
                coachDetails.setEmailAddr(email);
                coachDetails.setMidName(mid_name);
                coachDetails.setNickName(nick);
                coachDetails.setOriginState(state);
                coachDetails.save();

 //                    CoachDetails details = SQLite.select()
 //                            .from(CoachDetails.class)
//                            .querySingle();

 //                    Log.d(TAG, "CId from db:\t" + details.getCoachId() + " first_name:\t" + details.getFirstName()); // name is null and id is showing properly

 //                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Login Failed with Error Code:\t" + response.code(),
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                loginBtn.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Coach> call, Throwable t) {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Unable to Login...Check Your Connection or Credentials",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Can someone point out where it's going wrong?

Comment: first thing your coach is array instead of entity on response.

Comment: I am still able to get fields from response, I have tested that the problem is in saving or reading data

Comment: how is it possible, make sure you posted the correct json format in above example ..?

Comment: can you show `Coach` class ??

Comment: Ok I have edited to show Coach class. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: still confusing.. why in `Coach` class your coach_details is object instead array. while in json its array ...!!!

Comment: I think that's a mistake in json response and oversight on my part as login details is for only one user and should not be array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this problem by adding `@Column` annotation to the remaining fields in my model class. The problem was I moved from `ActiveAndroid to DBFlow` and forgot to properly annotate my fields before calling them.

I am getting the desired output now.

Answer (score 0):

Is my save done properly or my read query is wrong?

> Try below solution...

```
 private void attemptLogin(String username, String pwd) {
    Call<Coach> call = RestClient.getRestInstance()
            .getLoginService()
            .loginCoach("testcoach@gmail.com", "123@abcd"); // TODO: 12/17/2018 Use input values

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Coach>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Coach> call, Response<Coach> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {


                updateData(response.body())


            } else {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Login Failed with Error Code:\t" + response.code(),
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                loginBtn.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Coach> call, Throwable t) {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Unable to Login...Check Your Connection or Credentials",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}



private void updateData(Coach coach){

     coach_id = coach.getCoachDetails().getCoachId();

     new MyAsyncTask (this,coach.getCoachDetails()).execute();


     //add here AsynTask and save this `coachDetails` object inside the `doBackground()` method.

}
```

**Note :- Try to do all database work on Some background thread or you will get ANR Error on some device. Because you are doing all operation on the UI Thread.**

Example:-

```
 class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private Context context;
        private CoachDetails coachDetails;

        public MyAsyncTask(Context context,CoachDetails coachDetails) {
        this.coachDetails=coachDetails;
        this.context=context;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            coachDetails.save();
         return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {


     //                    CoachDetails details = SQLite.select()
 //                            .from(CoachDetails.class)
//                            .querySingle();

 //                    Log.d(TAG, "CId from db:\t" + details.getCoachId() + " first_name:\t" + details.getFirstName()); // name is null and id is showing properly

 //                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

        }
    }
```

Note: Insertion will takes time to insert row into database. You are accessing it without waiting.

After doing these things your data isn't displaying then your database is empty.
Follow this [Tutorial](https://medium.com/@marco_cattaneo/dbflow-4-part-1-getting-started-bb90ef261b2f) And Understand DBFlow.

Comment: I called coachDetails.save() with fields set from response. Where did you do yours?

Comment: check inside onResponse of Call

Comment: Thanks I have fixed it. Check my answer, it was oversight on my side